# How to transpose or pivot data of a text file in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep, transpose

I have an input text file in unix with this kind of data.

```
Event_date:20190512044638
Error_code:5858
Event_type:GPRS data
Duration:772
Missing_provider_id:46009

Event_date:20190512044638
Error_code:780678

Event_date:20190512064535
Error_code:5858
Event_type:GPRS data
Duration:2172
Missing_provider_id:722310
```

i want this data to be in this output format:

```
Event_date      Error_code  Event_type  Duration  Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858        GPRS data   772       46009
20190512044638  780678      
20190512064535  5858        GPRS data   2172      722310
```

I tried a combination of awk and sed commands, but didn't work out.
How can i achieve this output?

```
Event_date:20190512044638
Error_code:5858
Event_type:GPRS data
Duration:772
Missing_provider_id:46009

Event_date:20190512044638
Error_code:780678

Event_date:20190512064535
Error_code:5858
Event_type:GPRS data
Duration:2172
Missing_provider_id:722310
```

---

i want this data to be in this output format:

```
Event_date      Error_code  Event_type  Duration  Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858        GPRS data   772       46009
20190512044638  780678      
20190512064535  5858        GPRS data   2172      722310
```

Comment: please show the command you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk and 2D arrays:

```
awk '
BEGIN {                         
    r=2                                           # data records in a start from 2
    FS=":"                                        # split at :
    OFS="\t"                                      # tab separated fields
    a[0][0]                                       # initialize a array
}
$0!="" {                                          # for nonempty records
    if(!($1 in a[0])) {                           # add keys to headers when needed
        a[0][$1]=++f                              # for lookups
        a[1][f]=$1                                # for printing
    }
    a[r][a[0][$1]]=$2                             # store value
    next
}
{                                                 # empty record -> new array record
    r++
}
END {                                             # after records are processed
    # delete a[0][0]                              # 
    for(i=1;i<=r;i++)                             # iterate records
        for(j=1;j<=f;j++)                         # iterate fields
            printf "%s%s",a[i][j],(j==f?ORS:OFS)  # output
}
' file | column -t -s $'\t'                       # column used for pretty-print
```

Output:

```
Event_date      Error_code  Event_type  Duration  Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858        GPRS data   772       46009
20190512044638  780678
20190512064535  5858        GPRS data   2172      722310
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` may do: (tab separated fields)

PS this will fail if on field is missing, all need to come in order.

```
awk -F: 'NR==1 {print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9} {print $2,$4,$6,$8,$10}'  RS= ORS='\n' OFS='\t' file
Event_date      Error_code      Event_type      Duration        Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858    GPRS data       772     46009
20190512044638  780678
20190512064535  5858    GPRS data       2172    722310
```

---

A more generic solution:

```
awk -F: 'NR==1 {print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s\t",$i;print ""}'  RS= ORS='\n' OFS='\t' file
Event_date      Error_code      Event_type      Duration        Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858    GPRS data       772     46009
20190512044638  780678
20190512064535  5858    GPRS data       2172    722310
```

`NR==1 {print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9}` can be set to some static header like `NR==1 {print "F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"}` etc

Comment: While this works on the example, this will give very poor results if the second record would not have an error code, but a duration or event_type.

Comment: @kvantour That is true.

Comment: I believe the best way would be to use key-value pairs. The nasty thing is to make it in nice columns. If you would use `awk` with OFS which is not a space, you could parse everything with `column` to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

here is another one

```
awk -F: -v RS= 'BEGIN   {OFS=FS}
                NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)
                           if(!($i in h)) {h[$i]; ho[++c]=$i}; 
                         next}
                FNR==1  {for(i=1;i<=c;i++) printf "%s",ho[i] (i==c?ORS:OFS)}
                        {delete v;
                         for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) v[$i]=$(i+1);
                         for(i=1;i<=c;i++) printf "%s", v[ho[i]] (i==c?ORS:OFS)}' file{,} | 
column -ts:

Event_date      Error_code  Event_type  Duration  Missing_provider_id
20190512044638  5858        GPRS data   772       46009
20190512044638  780678
20190512064535  5858        GPRS data   2172      722310
```

no 2D arrays, but needs to scan the file twice to get all header info in order not to keep any data in memory, but to process the lines as they appear.