# How to convert rows to columns in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to convert my rows to column in linux

I have tried with some grep command its not worked out.

Say my output file look like

**cat file1.txt**

```
Slno : 1
Name : Google
Age : 20
Gender : Male
Exp : 10
Date : 10.10.19

Slno : 2
Name : Yahoo
Age : 21
Gender : Female
Exp : 11
Date : 11.11.19
```

**I wanted my output to be**

```
Slno    Name      Age    Gender     Exp        Date

1       Google    20     Male       10        10.10.19

2       Yahoo     21     Female     11        11.11.19
```

Comment: This task is beyond the intended use of `grep` or `sed`. You'll want to consider using `awk` or other scripting language.

Comment: Can you tell the suitable command for this by using awk

Comment: I think I just answer to a similar question. This might work for you out-of-the-box or with minor tweaking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761602/4162356

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `sed` is as below.

```
 ( echo -e 'Slno\nName\nAge\nGender\nExp\nDate'; sed '/^\s*$/d;s/^.*:\s*//g' file1.txt ) | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 6 printf "%s\t%-20s%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n\n"
```

Execution flow:
Sub-shell echo header first, then `sed` read file and removes all empty lines as well as column names, resulting in header on top and then data only, on per line basis.
null terminated lines from sub-shell is passed to `xargs`. which read in a group of 6 args (no. of columns) and passes to `printf`.

You can adjust format string as per possible field width.

Comment: It uses `sed`... and `tr`, and `xargs` and `printf`. A bump for including `sed` though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty hardcoded hack in perl:

```
$ cat bar|./foo.pl
Slno    Name    Age Gender  Exp Date
1   Google  20  Male    10  10.10.19
2   Yahoo   21  Female  11  11.11.19

$ cat foo.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %myhash;

print("Slno\tName\tAge\tGender\tExp\tDate\n");

while (<>) {
  if (/^(\S+)\s+\:\s+(.+)$/) {
    $myhash{$1} = $2;
  } else {
    print($myhash{'Slno'}."\t".$myhash{'Name'}."\t".$myhash{'Age'}."\t".$myhash{'Gender'}."\t".$myhash{'Exp'}."\t".$myhash{'Date'}."\n");
    undef %myhash;
  }
}
```

Comment: note, needs extra empty line in file1.txt to print last entry :)

Answer (score 0):

To convert rows into columns using gawk you can put the values into an associative array. Assuming your data is in `file.txt`

```
$ cat file.txt 
Slno : 1
Name : Google
Age : 20
Gender : Male
Exp : 10
Date : 10.10.19

Slno : 2
Name : Yahoo
Age : 21
Gender : Female
Exp : 11
Date : 11.11.19
```

You can treat the records as being separate by blank lines (NF > 2), and put columns `$1` and `$3` into an associative array `val`.

Once all records have been processed, iterate through the number of records, then iterate through the values in the associative array. Hence:

```
$ awk < file.txt 'BEGIN{rec=1;} {if (NF>2) val[rec][$1]=$3; else rec++;} \
      END {for (i=1;i<=rec;i++) {for (j in val[i]) \
           {printf "%s ",val[i][j];} printf "\n"; }printf "\n";}' | column -t
10.10.19  10  20  Google  Male    1
11.11.19  11  21  Yahoo   Female  2
```